# no such file to load -- rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I'm newly switched over to the mac.  I installed Passenger today.  I installed the Passender preferences pane tool which required RubyCocoa.  Now script/console won't run.  The error message is:

no such file to load -- rubygems

Prior to installing the passenger-related files this seems to have worked fine.

Any ideas?

```
 James
```

Comment: A little more information:

I now seem to have two installations of Ruby:

/opt/local/bin, 1.8.7 patch level 174
/usr/bin, 1.8.7 patch level 72

If I disable the one in /opt/local/bin (by renaming ruby and irb to ruby.bak and irb.bak) then script/console works.

/opt/local/bin and /opt/local/sbin are the first two entries in my PATH environment variable but I don't know what the PATH value was before I Started mucking around today.  I presume there's a better solution than just renaming the two files, yes?

Comment: what happens if you try to run "gem"?

Comment: There was only one install of gem (MacPorts' rb-rubygems hadn't been installed).  When I ran "gem list" it happily showed all the gems I'd previously installed.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with installing Ruby Enterprise edition. The default gem installation path is where ever /usr/bin/ruby has it's library files.

So you'll need to install all of your gems again for REE.

Either run the version of gem that comes with REE /opt/local/bin/gem or provide an --install-dir option pointing to the REE lib/gems/1.8 directory.

As in:

```
$ /opt/bin/gem install gems
```

or

```
$ gem install --install-dir /opt/lib/gem/1.8 gems
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  Looks like the situation was a little different.  I inadvertently installed MacPort's Ruby.  I've uninstalled MacPorts and reinstalled everything (except Ruby) and it looks like I'm back in business.

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed REE because Passenger suggests it. Turns out the solution is still the same